# SetWinEventHook is hooking events from "olemainthreadwndclass" only

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have program that hooks for all application events. My program is always run as administrator. 
Whenever I am trying to get the events It only hooks for the events which coming from the class 
***"olemainthreadwndclass"***. It is working properly on a sample application both user mode and admin mode. 
The same code copied to my project is not working. The code is referred below.

*Here is the CMainFrame.cpp ..*

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void ShutdownMSAA()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(hook);
    UnhookWinEvent(HookCreateToHide);
    UnhookWinEvent(HookNameChange);
    UnhookWinEvent(HookFocus);
    UnhookWinEvent(HookSysCapEnd);
    UnhookWinEvent(HookSysForeGrnd);
    CoUninitialize();
}

void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK tEmphook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if(hwnd)
    { 
        TCHAR szWinClassName[256];
        if(GetClassName(hwnd, szWinClassName, sizeof(szWinClassName)/sizeof(TCHAR)-1))
        {
            CString szGetWindowsClass(szWinClassName);
            if( szGetWindowsClass.CollateNoCase("SysTreeView32") != 0 &&
                szGetWindowsClass.CollateNoCase("SysListView32") != 0 &&
                szGetWindowsClass.CollateNoCase("msctls_statusbar32") != 0 &&
                szGetWindowsClass.CollateNoCase("#32770") != 0  &&
                szGetWindowsClass.CollateNoCase("OleMainThreadWndClass") != 0) 
            {
                OutputDebugString("#########################");
                CString szdwEventThread = ""; 
                szdwEventThread.Format(": %ld",dwEventThread);
                szGetWindowsClass += szdwEventThread;
                OutputDebugString(szGetWindowsClass);
            }  
        }
    }
} 

void InitializeMSAA()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    g_hook = SetWinEventHook( 
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND, 0, HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 

    HookCreateToHide = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE,EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE, 0,
             HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 

    HookNameChange = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE, 0, 
             HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 

    HookFocus = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, 0, 
             HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 

    HookSysCapEnd = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, 0,
             HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 

    HookSysForeGrnd = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0,
             HandleWinEvent, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); 
} 
CMainFrame::CMainFrame():Obj_SecondaryClass(NULL)
{
    AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON); 
    Obj_SecondaryClass = new SecondaryClass();
    Obj_SecondaryClass->SetActive(TRUE);
}

CMainFrame::~CMainFrame()
{
    Obj_SecondaryClass->SetActive(FALSE);
    delete Obj_SecondaryClass;
}

int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    try
    {
        if(CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }   
        EnterCriticalSection(&FirstCSec); 
        InitializeMSAA(); 
        LeaveCriticalSection(&FirstCSec);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if(!CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
        return FALSE; 

    cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | FWS_ADDTOTITLE;

    cs.dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0);
    return TRUE;
} 

void CMainFrame::OnSetFocus(CWnd* )
{ 
}

BOOL CMainFrame::OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo)
{ 
    return CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo);
}


LRESULT CMainFrame::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{  
    HANDLE hThread2;
    DWORD dwSessionID; 

    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_NCACTIVATE : 
            break;

        case WM_WINDOWS_LOGON : 
            break;

         case WM_APPBLOCK :
            MySelf::Me()->m_StatusOne = TRUE;
             break;

         case WM_UNAPPBLOCK:
            MySelf::Me()->m_StatusTwo = FALSE;
             break;

         case WM_APPBLOCKMSG:
             Obj_SecondaryClass->ChangeFunOne(); 
             break; 

        case WM_DESTROY: 

        case WM_QUIT: 

        case WM_ENDSESSION:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return CFrameWnd::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

*Here is the MainApplication.cpp ..*

```
MainApplication::MainApplication()
{ 
}

MainApplication theApp; 

BOOL MainApplication::InitInstance()
{    

    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec); 
    InitializeCriticalSection(&appBlocker_cCritSec);   

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls); 
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();  

    CMainFrame* pFrame = new CMainFrame;
    if (!pFrame)
        return FALSE; 
    m_pMainWnd = pFrame; 
    pFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | FWS_ADDTOTITLE, 
        NULL,
        NULL);

    pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    pFrame->UpdateWindow(); 
    return TRUE;
} 

int MainApplication::ExitInstance()
{ 
    return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

Please Support me, Thanks in advance,

Comment: `It only hooks for the events which coming from the class "olemainthreadwndclass".` Could you post some sample output to support this? The way the `if` condition is written in the code you posted, `OutputDebugString("#########################");
` would not get executed for `"olemainthreadwndclass"`.

Comment: It will not give any output doesn't mean it will not hook. For getting event hooked from classes other than  *"olemainthreadwndclass"*  , we are  doing the comparison there, But it is not hitting means there is no events are hooking other than the compared one's.

Comment: @AkhilVSuku My previous comment was to point that the OP gave no indication of how exactly it was failing, or how it was determined that it was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because make sure that your `.exe` is running under the same user space. ie, an `.exe` running under `SYSTEM` can not hook the events under the `'User_Name' User`. Even though we are running an `.exe` in `"Run as Administrator"` mode from `'User_Name' User` having administrator privilege will always run under the `'User_Name' User` only.